# JSLT - are there global variables?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jslt

I am looping through a for loop, I want to store the minimum value in a String.
But when I use `let` keyword, I think it is creating a local variable.
Is there a way to assign value to a global variable within a function in a for loop.

```
let ranking = 
{ 
 "DEC": 0,
 "SBS" : 1,
 "CON" : 2,
 "GCS" : 3,
 "GMS" : 4,
 "FXP" : 5,
 "QAN" : 6, 
 "REF" : 7,
 "PRO" : 8
}

let minRankSegment = "DEC"


def findMinRankSegment(segment)
  if(get-key($ranking, $segment, 100)  <= get-key($ranking, $minRankSegment))
    $segment
  else 
    let minRankSegment = $segment
    $minRankSegment
  

{for (.payload) 

  "data" : {
    "segment" :findMinRankSegment(.tag)
   }
}
```

Below is my input

```
{ "payload" : 
   [
    {"tag":"ABC"},
    {"tag":"DEC"},
    {"tag":"QAN"}
   ]
}
```

I am expecting the output to be

```
{
  "data" : {
    "segment" : "DEC",
  }
}
```

But it is

```
{
  "data" : {
    "segment" : "QAN",
  }
}
```

Comment: according to doc `let` is a variable declaration in current scope. https://github.com/schibsted/jslt so, you have two variables. i don't see variable assignment in this language...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this one:

```js
let ranking = 
{
 "DEC": 0,
 "SBS": 1,
 "CON": 2,
 "GCS": 3,
 "GMS": 4,
 "FXP": 5,
 "QAN": 6, 
 "REF": 7,
 "PRO": 8
}

let minRankSegment = "DEC"

let minSegment = [for (.payload)
  .tag
  if(get-key($ranking, .tag, 100) <= get-key($ranking, $minRankSegment))
]

{
  "data": {
    "segment": $minSegment[0]
   }
}
```

I changed the object for loop to array for loop and then get the `tag` while your `if` expression is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `let` creates local variables, and you can't change them.

The way to solve this is with a recursive function, like this:

```
let ranking = { 
 "DEC": 0,
 "SBS" : 1,
 "CON" : 2,
 "GCS" : 3,
 "GMS" : 4,
 "FXP" : 5,
 "QAN" : 6, 
 "REF" : 7,
 "PRO" : 8
}

def find-lowest-ranking(tags)
  if (not($tags))
    null
  else if (size($tags) == 1)
    $tags[0].tag
  else 
    let rank = get-key($ranking, $tags[0].tag, 100)
    let lowest = find-lowest-ranking($tags[1 : ])
    if ($rank < get-key($ranking, $lowest, 100))
      $tags[0].tag
    else
      $lowest

{
  "data" : {
    "segment" : find-lowest-ranking(.payload),
  }
}
```

If we'd had `order by` or `sort()` you could have solved it more easily with:

```
[for (.payload) [.tag] order by get-key($ranking, .tag, 100)][0]
```